# ansible local connection from python API

Tags: python, ansible

I want write ansible script with python API to do:
    #ansible 127.0.0.1  --connection=local -m service -a 'name=lxc-net state=started enabled=yes'

```
127.0.0.1 | success >> {
    "changed": true,
    "enabled": true,
    "name": "lxc-net",
    "state": "started"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have connection=local specified. See line with `module_args='....`

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/runner/__init__.py#L109-L162) I saw transport=C.DEFAULT_TRANSPORT, # 'ssh', 'paramiko', 'local'

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# (c) 2012, Michael DeHaan <michael.dehaan@gmail.com>
# example of getting the uptime of all hosts, 10 at a time

import ansible.runner
import sys

# construct the ansible runner and execute on all hosts
results = ansible.runner.Runner(
    transport='local',
    pattern='*', forks=10,
    module_name='command', module_args='/usr/bin/uptime',
).run()

if results is None:
   print "No hosts found"
   sys.exit(1)

print "UP ***********"
for (hostname, result) in results['contacted'].items():
    if not 'failed' in result:
        print "%s >>> %s" % (hostname, result['stdout'])

print "FAILED *******"
for (hostname, result) in results['contacted'].items():
    if 'failed' in result:
        print "%s >>> %s" % (hostname, result['msg'])

print "DOWN *********"
for (hostname, result) in results['dark'].items():
    print "%s >>> %s" % (hostname, result)
```